# Get the location of a document inside a document library using xslt

Tags: xslt, document

I have a requirement where I need to get the location of a document(Library Name/Folder Name/SubFolder Name) inside a document library using XSLT. Can anyone help me?

For example i have

```
http://Mysite:2016/dms/xxxx-DMS-yyyy/Lists/LibraryName/FolderName/SubFolderName/FileName.docx
```

and my requirement is to get

```
http://Mysite:2016/dms/xxxx-DMS-yyyy/Lists/LibraryName/FolderName/SubFolderName/
```

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:value-of "@FileLeafRef />` should get you most if not all of what you want.

Some of it will have to be built manually or by using server variables, http://sympmarc.com/2007/10/19/data-view-web-part-parameters-based-on-server-variables/.

In that case, you would just use a concat to string them all together, `<xsl:value-of "concat($SomeVariable,"/",@FileLeafRef />`, but you shouldn't need to do a full URL, a relative url to the document should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I found the solution.

`<a id="{concat($currentId,'_Title')}">
     <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="url"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="hithighlightedproperties/HHTitle[. != '']">
                <xsl:call-template name="HitHighlighting">
                   <xsl:with-param name="hh" select="hithighlightedproperties/HHTitle" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
</a>`

```
     `<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
     <!--passed template parameter -->
     <xsl:param name="list"/>
     <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter)">
            <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after($list,$delimiter),$delimiter)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
            <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
            <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,$delimiter)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

`